# Terms aggregation not giving buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying a simple terms aggregation but the result is not creating buckets.  Here is a sample document:

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 27330,
      "max_score": 0.8293952,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "policy",
            "_type": "policy",
            "_id": "W0051311PNWO",
            "_score": 0.8293952,
            "_source": {
               "productname": "UK CARGO",
               "alternateproductname": "ABC39393939",
               "brokername": "Name***",
               "agentname": "Name***",
               "policyref": "ABC33333",
               "client": "International Cargo Limited",
               "addressline1": "",
               "post/zipcode": "",
               "telephone": null,
               "bapolicyendorseid": 123334,
               "prevcertnum": "",
               "policystatus": "Endorsed",
               "@version": "1",
               "@timestamp": "2015-10-09T11:11:02.018Z"
            }
         },
```

Here is the aggregate search (in sense):

```
get policy/policy/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "statuses": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "policystatus"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the equivalent of:

```
select policystatus, count(*) from policy group by policystatus
```

The result is not showing buckets.  It is showing regular document results:

```
{
   "took": 6,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 227398,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "policy",
            "_type": "policy",
            "_id": "04/QQQ/04UKI0018",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "productname": "2 RES 01/09/04",
               "alternateproductname": "2 RES 01/09/04",
               "brokername": "Blah LTD",
               "agentname": "Insurance",
               "policyref": "blah",
               "client": "blah",
               "addressline1": "blah",
               "post/zipcode": "blah",
               "telephone": null,
               "bapolicyendorseid": 21427,
               "prevcertnum": "04UKI0018",
               "policystatus": "Pending",
               "@version": "1",
               "@timestamp": "2015-10-09T11:10:10.146Z"
            }
         },
```

Comment: 1) Try to use POST instead of GET, 2) you can set `"size": 0` in order to only get the aggregation buckets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
GET /policy/policy/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "statuses": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "policystatus"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

meaning capital letters `GET` and `search_type=count` to get only the buckets, not also the `hits`.

Comment: Note that `search_type=count` will be [deprecated as of ES 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/_search_changes.html#_literal_search_type_count_literal_deprecated), and specifying `"size": 0` will be the only way to not return hits.

Comment: Thanks, @val.  I didn't realize the capital GET made a difference.  It definitely does though.